# Possibility of intentional downvote sabotage?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, serial-voting

Sorry if this is off-topic but this is my first question and I haven't been around the meta page very much.

I checked my daily reputation gain today and I found three new downvotes on my answers. The first one was on an answer from about a week ago and I could very well believe that it's authentic, but the other two are on answers which haven't been active for months, and more suspiciously they are timestamped from within the same minute. And although I don't think any of these answers were particularly well-done, I find it odd that they came with no comment explaining their issue with my answer.

Because of this I think somebody got upset with me and is now downvoting my old answers deliberately to take down my reputation. Frankly I don't care too much about my reputation (it's just internet points, I care more about helping people) but it is a bit annoying because this is the first time during my time on the site that any of my answers have dipped into the negatives, and given the number of answers I've posted (although others who've been around longer have certainly done more) I was sort of happy with that "perfect" record.

I was wondering if there's any standard procedure for this, or if anyone else finds this behavior a bit peculiar?

Thanks

Comment: Apart of the duplicate,  you could also go to [Math Mods' Office](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20352/math-mods-office).

Comment: Thanks, if the automatic check doesn't pick it up I might check that out

Comment: But do give the automatic check a day or two to make its rounds.